# How do you use special letters (danish) in R-studio?

Tags: r, character-encoding, rstudio

I am from Denmark and need to be able to use danish letters in my R-code.

If I add some code like:

```
print("Århus er bare øv...")
```

and save it as an R-script file in R-studio, the next time I open the file in R-studio I get:

```
print("?rhus er bare ?v...")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When saving your file, use File -> Save with encoding and select e.g. "UTF-8". If the file is read incorrectly next time, use File -> Reopen with encoding.

You may also change the RStudio preferences (Tools -> Global options / General->Default text encoding) and set "UTF-8".